# Expect.extend doesn`t work. TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, ts-jest, vitest

I made the same settings for running vitest like in this article: https://medium.com/@zamin_mirzad/how-to-setup-vite-js-react-js-typescript-vitest-js-6e01b6436c6a

But when I run yarn test I have this issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s5Ae.png

And it can`t find any matchers https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJlRc.png

Please, help me!) Maybe I need something to the config?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The first step here would be to provide your code instead of pictures of your code

Comment: I was also debugging the same issue, google search for the error landed me here. The import in the medium article needs slight modification where you need to `import * as matchers from "@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers";` instead of `import matchers from "@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers";` as suggested.
This is highlighted in issue [439 here](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/439)

Comment: The above should be an answer and marked as correct